# How to weight ranks?

Tags: ranking, weights, function, ranks

I have a set of responses ranked by my participants. For example, they gave responses A, B, C and ranked them as 3, 2, 1 (or C, B, A). I computed relative frequencies of each responses (A, B, C) and their mean ranks (as weighted average).

Now, I would like to connect these to pieces of information into a single score for each response. I could have just multiplied the frequency with the mean rank but I do not believe that the ranks are perfectly interval. E.g., ranks 1 and 2 are very important to the participant, while ranks 4 and 5 may be just clutter.

Hence, I am looking for a function that would take this into account. Specifically, I would like the function to look like a flat hook of sorts. I.e, to weight the ranks 1 and 2 highly, then plummet and finally rank the rank 5 as almost unimportant.

I am, however, struggling with coming up with a function that would both work and be elegant enough. It is for a scientific paper, so I also need to be able to use something that doesn't look as if it was created to create the outcome I need.

I would greatly appreciate any ideas you might have,

Comment: 1. Our ability to suggest a function to you when you barely describe it is going to be difficult. Could you perhaps draw it? 2. On the other hand, I get a sense we might be in the vicinity of an X-Y problem. Perhaps it might be useful to explore whether there's other ways to approach the underlying issue than this one.

Comment: Scaling the ranks and then taking a weighted mean would do it I think. The weights in the weighted mean would be proportional to the importance given to the type of response.

Comment: Thank you! How would you scale them please?